# Why my Oracle 10g does not have the scott account?

Tags: oracle10g

I am using oracle 10g and I need to unlock the scott account. But when I am trying this, it is showing that the user account does not exist. How can I resolve it?

[image]

Comment: If you didn't install it as part of the database, the installation script is $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/scott.sql

Comment: Thank u! It solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't install it as part of the database, the installation script is $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/scott.sql

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has the scripts to install their schemas on GitHub:

- The Scott schema installation script may be in the `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/scott.sql` file of an Oracle installation or is in [Oracle's `dotnet-db-samples` GitHub repository](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/blob/master/schemas/scott.sql).
- The HR, OE, PM, SH, IX and BI sample schemas installation scripts can be found in the `$ORACLE_HOME/demo/schema` directory of an Oracle installation or in [Oracle's `db-sample-schemas` GitHub repository](https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas/releases/latest) and has an has an [installation guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/comsc/installing-sample-schemas.html#GUID-1E645D09-F91F-4BA6-A286-57C5EC66321D) in the Oracle documentation pages.